# java.lang.AbstractMethodError with javassist and abstract generic classes

Tags: java, generics, reflection, osgi, javassist

i want to execute a method within a generated class that extends an abstract generic one but it throws java.lang.AbstractMethodError.

PS: the generic class is not generated

Example:

```
public abstract class AbstractSpecification<T> implements Specification<T>{
    public abstract boolean isSatisfiedBy(T t); 
    public Specification<T> and(final Specification<T> specification) {
        return new AndSpecification<T>(this, specification);
    }
}
```

The generated class is

```
ClassPool pool = new ClassPool(true);
pool.insertClassPath(new ClassClassPath(AbstractSpecification.class));
CtClass abstractClazz = pool.get("com.mycompany.AbstractSpecification");
CtClass myclass = pool.makeClass("ValidAge");
myclass.setSuperclass(abstractClazz);
.
.
.
```

Invoking `isSatisfiedBy` works but `and` throws `java.lang.AbstractMethodError`

Comment: I assume you are doing this in a bundle inside OSGi runtime and that is why you added the `osgi` label. If that is indeed the case you need to provide more details about your environment as well as where and how you generate and invoke the method.

Answer (score 2):

Javassist does not implement bridge methods for you, this remains your responsibility. Therefore, you need to implement two methods when subclassing your `AbstractSpecification`, the actual method and the bridge of the erasure of `T`.

For example, for implementing `AbstractSpecification<Foo>`, you would need to implement a method `isSatisfiedBy(Foo)` and the bridge `isSatisfiedBy(Object)` where the latter method only invokes the former including a casting.

If this seems to much work, have a look at [Byte Buddy](https://github.com/raphw/byte-buddy) which handles bridge methods transparently for you.